# Neural Network epoch and max_iter in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What is the difference or relationship between the Neural Network (NN) epoch and the max_iter parameter in scikit-learn?

For instance, as it can be seen in the code, evaluating the NN model for max_iter from 1 up to 10000 and evaluating for each iteration the Mean Absolute Error can be seen as the epoch? See image/link below, please!

[image]

Thank you very much!

```
for i in range(1,10000,10):

    clf = MLPRegressor(max_iter=i, solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-6, activation='relu', # melhorou e muito o treino com relu
                       hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_sizes, random_state=1)

     clf.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

     mae_B = cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", cv=10)

     print i, float(-mae_B.mean()), clf.score(X_train_scaled, y_train), clf.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

`max_iter` is equivalent to maximum number of epochs you want the model get trained on. It is called as maximum because the learning could get stopped before reaching the maximum number of iterations as well based on other termination criteria - `n_iter_no_change`. Hence do not loop through with different max_iterations, try to tweak the `tol` and `n_iter_no_change` if you want to avoid the overfitting.

Try the following and set the reasonably enough epochs in `max_iter` and then play with `n_iter_no_change` and `tol`. Reference [Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html)

```
clf = MLPRegressor(max_iter=50, solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-6, activation='relu', 
                     hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_sizes, random_state=1,
                     tol=1e-3, n_iter_no_change = 5)

clf.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

mae_B = cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", cv=10)

print i, float(-mae_B.mean()), clf.score(X_train_scaled, y_train), clf.score(X_test_scaled, y_test)
```